# HTML Float Property

Tags: html, css, css-float

```
<nav>
    <div class="row">
       <img src="resources/img/logo-white.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
           <ul class="main-nav">
               <li><a href="#">Food delivery</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Our cities</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
           </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

I have the code above for a navigation bar in an Udemy tutorial I am following.
The CSS Source Code for the `navbar` is the following:

```
.row {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.main-nav {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

The part I am confused on is for the img in the div with the `class="row"` why is it that the image is put off to the top left even though I didn't set the float property of the `img` to `float: left;`. 
As you can see in the `image` below, that `white` logo is positioned to the `top` `left` even though I never set the `float` property to `left`. But for the `ul` with the `class="main-nav"` I had to set the `float` property to `right`.

[image]

Comment: The default direction of your document is `ltr` and the default `display` property of the image is `inline` so the image "floating" left.

Comment: Hi! What does does ltr mean for default direction?

Comment: Oh ok! I see now, don't know why I didn't realize this simple thing before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

img is a inline element & ul is a block level element. that means that ul would take the 100% width and be on a new line whereas img would take its specific width. and by default the direction is ltr so we have all inline elements floating to the left.

Answer (score 0):

The logo `displays` on the `left` side as the default direction for every HTML element has the "rule" `LTR`, so that means even if you haven't made a `float: left` line it will, though `display` at the `left` side.

Have a look at [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html), it should help you with something, happy programming!